# How to create Placeholder in AG-Grid Text field

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-validation

I have an editable ag-grid. How can I add placeholders to empty cells (they should disappear when cells are edited)?

```
cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: (params) => {
        debugger;
    const { filterOptionKey, placeholder } = params;
    return `Enter the Athelte`;
  },
  filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            filterPlaceholder: 'Enter the Athelte '
        }
```

},
we try the above code but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/) to do this like so!

```
{
  headerName: 'Text Editor',
  field: 'color1',
  cellRenderer: (params) => params.value || <span class="light-color">'Click to edit!'</span>,
  cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    maxLength: 20,
  },
},
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4dSuLBi12x5Xw04h?pen=index.jsx&preview)

Comment: can we change the color of text like placeholder color

Comment: can we  change the color when we write something in cell

Comment: @MuhammadRaun what is not working?

Comment: cellRenderer: (params) => params.value || <span class="light-color">'Click to edit!'</span>, 
when i insert this code then its ag grid is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256755/discussion-between-muhammad-raun-and-naren-murali).

Comment: @MuhammadRaun are you using react or angular?

Comment: Simple JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```js
const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Athlete',
    field: 'athlete',
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
      const isEditing = params.node.gridOptions.api.getEditingCells().length > 0;
      return isEditing ? params.value : 'Enter the Athlete';
    },
  },
  // Other columns...
];

const gridOptions = {
  // other options...
};

// Create the grid
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

// Set the data
gridOptions.api.setRowData(yourRowData);
```

In this example, the **valueFormatter** checks whether any cell is being edited using **params.node.gridOptions.api.getEditingCells().length > 0**. If a cell is being edited, it displays the actual value; otherwise, it displays the placeholder text. Note that this approach might not be as visually clean as using custom cell renderers, but it's a simpler solution using the available options in ag-Grid.
[image: Here showing data ...]

- Here, showing data only...

[image: here where is nothing at there showing Click to edit! and you can edit...]

- Here, where is nothing at there showing Click to edit! and you can edit...